# Android: creating a custom recyclerview enter animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

I’m trying to recreate an animation in Android’s RecyclerView that I have found on the web for loading a grid of pictures. In particular, I’m trying to recreate the “Seker” run effect. It's the third option from the bottom on the right-hand side:

https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingAnimations/

I have a recycler view in my app showing a 2 column, 3 row grid of images that I want to display with the same “reveal” effect whenever I first load the recycler view items.

My first thought was to create an item animation XML and also a layout animation XML which would apply the item animation to each child in the layout:

Item animation XML:

```
<alpha
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1" />

<translate
    android:fromYDelta="100"
    android:toYDelta="0" />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="80%"
    android:fromYScale="80%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:toYScale="100%" />
```

Layout animation XML:

```
<gridLayoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:columnDelay="10%"
    android:direction="top_to_bottom|left_to_right"
    android:rowDelay="10%" />
```

Then I could trigger the layout animation programmatically:

```
private fun runLayoutAnimation() {
    val context = recyclerView.context
    val controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_xml)

    recyclerView.layoutAnimation = controller
    recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation()
}
```

It did not look the same, to say the least. When I looked at the code behind the web version I'm trying to mimic (yay opensource!), it looks to be two animations running in tandem:

```
    'Seker': {

        revealer: true,

        revealerOrigin: '50% 100%',

        animeRevealerOpts: {

            duration: 500,

            delay: function(t,i) {

                return i*50;

            },

            easing: [0.7,0,0.3,1],

            translateY: [100,0],

            scaleY: [1,0]

        },

        animeOpts: {

            duration: 500,

            easing: [0.7,0,0.3,1],

            delay: function(t,i) {

                return i*50;

            },

            opacity: {

                value: [0,1],

                duration: 400,

                easing: 'linear'

            },

            translateY: [100,0],

            scale: [0.8,1]

        }

    }
```

https://github.com/codrops/GridLoadingAnimations/blob/master/js/main.js

Animations are not my strong suit, so any advice would be appreciated on how to solve this.

**My question is: how can I recreate these animations for loading a recycler view especially since they seem to be two animations?**

Comment: Perhaps, you can try following this tutorial https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

Comment: Thanks, @BachVu. I took a look at the guide, and that guy is doing what I tried with the item/layout animation combo. I didn't see an example or a way to have two layout animations playing at the same time. Or at least combine the two animations into one that would achieve the same effect.

Comment: I think you need to figure out a way to combine your animations in a single xml file